# Symfony3 Query Bulder?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am new to symfony 3 and I would like to understand how to get a value from a table according to the result found.
Let me explain :

According to the bass diagram below, each "produit" has a "poids"(nom) and a "valeur"(valeur)

view bdd:

[image: view bdd]

I would like in my basket view to display the total value of the weight according to the quantity of course.
For example, I have a product at 2kg and another at 0.300kg, it would have to result in the value of 2.3kg which is in the weight table.
I can not perform this "function".
Here is my PanierController.

```
 class PanierController extends Controller
{
    public function supprimerAction(SessionInterface $session, $id)
    {
    $panier = $session->get('panier');

    if (array_key_exists($id, $panier))
    {
        unset($panier[$id]);
        $session->set('panier', $panier);
        $this->addFlash('success', 'Article supprimé avec succès !');
    }

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('panier'));
}
public function ajouterAction(SessionInterface $session, Request $request, $id)
{

    if (!$session->has('panier')) {
        $session->set('panier', array());
    }
    $panier = $session->get('panier');

    if (array_key_exists($id, $panier)) {
        if ($request->query->get('qte') != null) {
            $panier[$id] = $request->query->get('qte');
        }
        $this->addFlash('success', 'Quantité modifié avec succès !');
    } else {
        if ($request->query->get('qte') != null) {
            $panier[$id] = $request->query->get('qte');
        } else {
            $panier[$id] = 1;
        }
        $this->addFlash('success', 'Article ajouté avec succès !');
    }

    $session->set('panier', $panier);


    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('panier'));
}

public function panierAction(SessionInterface $session)
{

    if (!$session->has('panier')) {
        $session->set('panier', array());
    }

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $produits = $em->getRepository('EcommerceBundle:Produits')->findArray(array_keys($session->get('panier')));



    return $this->render('EcommerceBundle:Default:panier/layout/panier.html.twig', array('produits' => $produits, 'panier' => $session->get('panier')));
}

public function livraisonAction()
{
    // servira pour l'adresse de livraison
    return $this->render('EcommerceBundle:Default:panier/layout/livraison.html.twig');
}

public function validationAction()
{
    return $this->render('EcommerceBundle:Default:panier/layout/validation.html.twig');


 }
}
```

If you need more information, please let me know.

Comment: Have you tried writing something in SQL first that works?

Answer (score 0):

@JasonRoman,

That is to say ?
For example to display the products in the Shopping Cart view, I use the ProductsRepository in the Shopping CartController:

```
    public function panierAction(SessionInterface $session)
{

    if (!$session->has('panier')) {
        $session->set('panier', array());
    }

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $produits = $em->getRepository('EcommerceBundle:Produits')->findArray(array_keys($session->get('panier')));



    return $this->render('EcommerceBundle:Default:panier/layout/panier.html.twig', array('produits' => $produits, 'panier' => $session->get('panier')));
}
```

ProductsRepository:

```
class ProduitsRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findArray($array) 
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
                ->select('u')
                ->where('u.id IN (:array)')
                ->setParameter('array', $array);
        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
}
```

The result is correct in the Cart view.
In the basket view, if I ask him to show me the total weight in the basket, I do:

```
{% Extends "::layout/layout.html.twig"%}
{% Set totalHT = 0%}
{% Set livraisonHT = 0%}
{% Block body%}

{% Set livraisonHT = livraisonHT + (panier[produit.id] * produit.poids.nom)%}
```

livraisonHT gives me the total weight

On the other hand, I do not know what function to write so that it shows me the corresponding value.
Currently I have in my basket:
One product at 2kg and another product at 0.3kg

```
{% Set livraisonHT = livraisonHT + (panier[produit.id] * product.poids.non)%}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have put my finger on something,
In my basket view, if I do a dump (produits) i get, that:

```
array:1 [▼
0 => Produits {#546 ▼
-id: 5
-image: Media {#445 ▶}
-gamme: Gamme {#396 ▶}
-marque: Marque {#467 ▶}
-tva: Tva {#563 ▼
  +__isInitialized__: true
  -id: 11
  -multiplicate: 0.83333333333334
  -nom: "TVA 20 %"
  -valeur: 20.0
   …2
}
-poids: Poids {#670 ▼
  +__isInitialized__: false
  -id: 209
  -nom: null
  -valeur: null
   …2
}
-categorie: Categories {#684 ▶}
-nom: "Phantom 4 Standard"
-resume: "le résumé"
-description: "La description longue"
-details: "details à voir"
-prix: 1000.0
-disponible: true
}
]
```

In "weight" the name and value are zero?